# Automatic Date Calculation - Based on start date in one cell and number of nights in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to auto fill the check out night box based on the data that populates in Arrival and Nights column. Is this possible?

It looks like this

```
 Arrival        Nights     Check out 
 6/17/2019         5       6/22/2019  (what I want calculated)
 6/18/2019         4       (empty cell I want autofilled)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(OR(A2="",B2=""),"",A2+B2)
```

and copy downwards:

[image]